# Representação de uma entidade em minha classe

Tags: c#

Tenho esse campo no banco: `ID_LIBERACAO` e na minha classe de domínio tenho assim:

```
[Table("Tabela")]
public class Tabela
[Key]
[DataBaseGenerated(DataBaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int IdLiberacao {get; set; }
```

Mesmo com o nome sem o sinal de sublinhado, a minha classe entende que está se referindo ao campo da tabela? Eliminei todos os underscore dos nomes dos campos e padronizei desta forma. Não tenho como testar ainda, até receber a liberação do cliente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Especifique o nome que está no banco, use **`annotation`**, veja:

```
[Table("Tabela")]
public class Tabela
[Key]
[DataBaseGenerated(DataBaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Column("ID_LIBERACAO")]
public int IdLiberacao {get; set; }
```

Referência: [DataAnnotation](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-classes-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Então, faço isso para todas as colunas que eu alterei o nome na classe? Eu fiz isso para todas

Comment: Sim, desta forma você terá o controle do mapeamento.

Comment: Edvaldo, caso o nome do atributo em minha classe seja igual ao do banco, eu não preciso usar o atributo Column, certo? Ou se já fiz em um, tenho que fazer em todos? Só uma dúvida.

Comment: Você pode fazer apenas nos casos que deseja customizar o mapeamento, não precisa fazer para todos.